# Calculate the average value of the numbers in a file

Tags: python, file, numbers

I am having a problem of calculating the average value of numbers in a file.
So far i have made a function that reads in files and calculate the number of lines. 
The file consists of many columns of numbers, but the column 8 is the one i need to calculate from.

```
def file_read():
     fname = input("Input filname: ")
     infile = open(fname,'r')
     txt = infile.readlines()
     print("opens",fname,"...")

num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(fname))

#The first line in the file is only text, so i subtract 1 
print("Number of days:",(num_lines-1))
```

The numbers are also decimals, so i use float.

This is my try on calculating the sum of numbers, 
which shall be divided by the number of lines  , but i comes an error, cuz the first line is text.

```
with open(fname) as txt:
         return sum(float(x)
               for line in txt
               for x in line.split()[8]
```

Is there a way i can get python to ignore the first line and just concentrate about the numbers down under?

Comment: Didn't get your question, You want to calculate the average value of number of  "lines" in file or just numbers in file?

Comment: just to make it clear i want to calculate the average value of numbers

Answer (score 0):

You could use `txt.readline()` to read the first line, but to stick with iterators way to do it, just drop the first line using iteration on file with `next`

```
with open(fname) as txt:
   next(txt)  # it returns the first line, we just ignore the return value
   # your iterator is now on the second line, where the numbers are
   for line in txt:
       ...
```

Side note: this is also very useful to skip title lines of files open with the `csv` module, that's where `next` is better than `readline` since csv title can be on multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
#regular expression for decimals
digits_reg = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+|\d+")

with open('''file name''', "r") as file:
    allNum = []
    #find numbers in each line and add them to the list
    for line in file:
        allNum.extend(digits_reg.findall(line))

#should be a list that contains all numbers in the file
print(alNum)
```